# I'm trying to the customzing the error format structure .for the Rest API

Tags: mongodb, rest, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to customize the error format with the below structure but not able to set the the error and             httpCodeMessage

**Error Fromat** :

```
 [
      {
          "headers": {},
           "body": {
            "timestamp": "2020-08-17T10:22:14.538+0000",
            "error": null,
             "message": "User Not Found in the system",
              "path": "/claims/search/",
              "httpCodeMessage": null
         },
         "statusCode": "BAD_REQUEST",
         "statusCodeValue": 400
     }
  ]
```

@ExceptionHandler(ValidationException.class)

```
 public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse[]> process(ValidationException ex, HttpServletRequest req) {
  return new ResponseEntity(Arrays.asList(generateErrorResponse(ex, req)), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
private Object generateErrorResponse(ValidationException ex, HttpServletRequest req) {
    ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse();
    if (ex.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("Resource Not Found")) {
        error.setTimestamp(new Date());
        error.setMessage(NOT_FOUND.value(), ex.getMessage());
        error.setPath(req.getRequestURI().toString());
        error.setError(ResponseEntity.status(NOT_FOUND));
        return ResponseEntity.status(NOT_FOUND).body(error);
    }
```

}

Can anyone suggest how to get the error and httpCodeMessage values .Is it possible to remove the statusCode and statusCodeValue attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You normally have to go to the original `HttpClientErrorException` and `getRawStatusCode()` to get the HTTP error code

[javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/HttpClientErrorException.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response .I tried to set the HttpClientErrorException and getRawStatusCode() but its is giivng some errors Can you suggest synttax please .